# Convert the format of date in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a code that makes an `ajax` call from a `php file`.
This `php file` returns some data from the database as `json`.
The data contains a column with `timestamp` type and this how it looks :

```
2015-10-24 18:04:28
```

but I want to convert this format to look like this :

```
1445724268000
```

I tried to use `Date.parse()` but when I `log.console` it I'm getting `NaN`

Comment: Why not `var timestamp = new Date('2015-10-24 18:04:28').getTime();` ?

Comment: @GökayGürcan This won't work on every browsers as this date string is not a perfectly valid date format. Will work on Chrome, but not on Firefox.

Comment: Ah, indeed. I didn't understand browser related restriction when I read the OP. My bad clearly, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"2015-10-24 18:04:28"` is not a valid parameter value for either `Date.parse()` or `new Date()`. Different browsers may interpret nonstandard values differently, so it might work for some people even though it's failing for you, depending on what browsers are being used.

According to [the ECMAScript 2015 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-time-string-format), the date string should be [a simplification of the ISO 8601 extended format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15): YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ (such as `"2015-10-24T18:04:28"`).

If you can replace the space character between the date and the time with the character `T`, your string should become an acceptable date string.

Here's a working example:

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
var outputs = document.querySelectorAll("span");

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
  (function(index){
    inputs[index].addEventListener("keyup",function(){updateOutput(index);});
  })(i);
  updateOutput(i);
}

function updateOutput(index){
  var date = new Date(inputs[index].value);
  outputs[index].innerHTML = date.getTime();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="2015-10-24 18:04:28" id="inputOne"/><span id="outputOne"></span> (works in Chrome, could fail in IE and Firefox)<br/>
<input type="text" value="2015-10-24T18:04:28" id="inputOne"/><span id="outputOne"></span> (works in all browsers)<br/>
<input type="text" value="October 24, 2015 18:04:28" id="inputOne"/><span id="outputOne"></span> (this usually works too, but isn't in the spec)
```

**Note:** Some sources (MDN) also indicate that a date string can be [an IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamp](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) (such as `"October 24, 2015 18:04:28"`) but this is not part of the actual spec, and might not be supported in future JavaScript implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Since timestamp received is a string,replace the space with `T`:

`var timestampString = "2015-10-24 18:04:28"; //Your input`

You just need to to convert it into a valid date format and use `getTime()` method.

`var timestamp = new Date(timestampString.replace(' ','T')).getTime();`

Answer (score 0):

`Date.getTime()` returns the epoch string (for example, `757382400000`)

So to convert your timestamp you can write:

```
var date = new Date(timestamp);
var epochString = date.getTime();
```

IF you output to the console (`console.log(epochString`), you'll end up with something like `757382400000`.

Comment: when I tried that I got  `Date {Invalid Date}` in console

Comment: Not all browsers can parse date when date is presented in this string format. Works in Chrome, but won't work on Firefox.

Comment: @AniketSinha oh. Just tried it. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

If the above format is constantly used, I would do something like this:

```
function formatDate(myFormat) {
  var dateTime = myFormat.split(" ");
  var myDate = new Date (dateTime[0]);
  var myTime = dateTime[1].split(":");   
  var result = new Date(
   myDate.getYear() + 1900, 
   myDate.getMonth(), 
   myDate.getDate(),
   myTime[0], 
   myTime[1],
   myTime[2], 
   0);
  return result;
}

var date = formatDate("2015-10-24 18:04:28");
alert(date.getTime());
```

This gives you the **local** date and time. You may want to switch to UTC values.

See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp for more information about dates.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j2cokszo/).