# Show row in table only if date variable is in current month

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, html-table

I draw table in my script where I display some data. One of columns in table is date variable.
If that date variable is in current month, I want its row to be displayed in table. Other words, if date is not in current month I want to hide whole row.

Date column is originally in ISO date format, but I convert it into DD.MM.YYYY. with this function:

```
var Date1 = MyDate;
function formatYMDtoDMY(s)
{
    var b = s.split(/\D/);
    return b[2] + '.' + b[1] + '.' + b[0] + '.';
}
```

than I call this function in my table, 3rd column in table:

```
$("#T1").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
  "<td align='left'>"+ID+"</td>" +
  "<td align='left'>"+UserName+"</td>" +
  "<td align='left'>"+formatYMDtoDMY(Date1)+"</td>"+
  "<td align='left'>"+City, State+"</td>"  +      
  "<td align='left'>"+Project name+"</td>"  +
  "<td align='left'>"+Additional info+"</td>"  +
  "</tr>");
```

I tried this way:

```
if(input.getFullYear() == currentDate.getFullYear()
   && input.getMonth() == currentDate.getMonth()) {
    //  than I post my table
   }  // but all I get displayed is only 1st date
```

I also thought I could catch 1st and last day of current month like this:

```
var date = new Date(), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);
var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);
```

but I don't know how to proceed with checking date column if it is between these variables and if yes to display row in my table.

Comment: Do you only care about hiding the row from the person viewing the page (e.g. through the use of CSS), or do you want to prevent the row from being added to the DOM altogether?

Comment: I only want to hide that row from being displayed. So it's the 1st choice.

Answer (score 0):

So I completely misunderstood your question.

The easiest thing will be to convert your ISO date into a real date. The JavaScript Date object understands the ISO date format, so you can create a date object by calling the constructor:

```
var myDateObj = new Date(MyDate);
```

Date objects work with logical operators, so we can use your firstDay and lastDay objects:

```
var isCurrent = (firstDay <= myDateObj && myDateObj <= lastDay);
```

You can use this to show and hide rows as you render your table.

```
$("#T1").append("<tr align='middle' class='" + isCurrent ? 'row-visible' : 'row-hidden' +"'>" +
  "<td align='left'>"+ID+"</td>" +
  "<td align='left'>"+UserName+"</td>" +
  "<td align='left'>"+formatYMDtoDMY(Date1)+"</td>"+
  "<td align='left'>"+City, State+"</td>"  +      
  "<td align='left'>"+Project name+"</td>"  +
  "<td align='left'>"+Additional info+"</td>"  +
  "</tr>");
```

Add CSS rules:

```
.row-hidden {
  display: none;
}

.row-visible {
  display: table-row;
}
```

You could wrap this up into a single function:

```
function isCurrentMonth(s) {
  var myDate = new Date(s);
  var date = new Date(), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
  var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);
  var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);
  return (firstDay <= myDate && myDate <= lastDay);
}
```

Comment: I've just realised that your Date1 object isn't a JavaScript Date object. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I get message Invalid Date on alert(myDateObj);

Comment: If MyDate is a string representation of an ISO-compliant date, then that shouldn't happen (https://jsfiddle.net/ywmvh9sp/ for an example). Can you confirm that MyDate is a string representation of an IOS-formatted date?

Comment: I get date as this 2017-01-12 00:00:00

Comment: I'm afraid there must be something else causing a problem. `var myDateObj = new Date('2017-01-12 00:00:00');` gives me a valid date object.

Comment: @Danilo put a letter T (instead of a space character) in between the date and time sections of the string (thus `2017-01-12T00:00:00`) to make it a valid simplification of the [ISO 8601 extended format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ), as explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683168/convert-the-format-of-date-in-javascript/34684157#34684157). Some browsers will accept values formatted differently but others will not. You can use JavaScript's string.prototype.replace() method for this if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, Thriggle - I didn't even notice the missing T when I copy pasted, although I believe that my answer is still valid for the question as written.